# How to add values to another array

Tags: java, arrays

Im working on this project,
I am stuck, the goal is to

`Read Input from a .txt file, one integer per line, Then put those integers into an array.`

After they are all in the array

I am supposed to take the values in the spots 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8, etc until the file is done. And add them, the five values per spot. And the sum of those i have to add into another Array.

There will be four less values in Array #2 than there will be in array #1.

After the two arrays are set i have to

Compare the two arrays, disregarding the first and last two values in array #1 and if the value of Array #1 is larger than the value in the same spot on array #2 + 0.999, I print out the location in array #1 of the larger value.

This is my code so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Asgn7
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {   
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("asgn7data.txt"));
        double[] array = new double[file.nextInt()];
        double[] newArray = new double[array.length - 4];
        double tempVal = 0;
        int j = 0;

        while(file.hasNext())
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++ )
        {
            array[i] = file.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }

        for(j = 0; j < array.length - 4; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                newArray[j] += array[j+k] / 5;  
            }



        }
        }




    }
}
```

Here's a picture of what the first Array should look like and the second array. We have to compare the values as shown, the shaded boxes are the values which would printed out because they are over 0.999 larger.

[image]

For example, The output would be 4,7,9,11,12 if this were the numbers in the file.

Comment: Whats not working with your current code?

Comment: Right now, I cant access array[i] outside of the loop and i need to do some calculations with it, And im not too sure how to Compare the values in the Arrays when they are a different size.

Comment: create a variable, and keep a running total (inside the loop add the value to the variable so int total = 0; and inside the loop do int nextval = file.nextInt(); then total += nextval, then array[i] = nextval ?

Comment: @James, Wouldn't that just give me all of the values of the arrays added? I only need 1-5, then 2-6, 3-7, then to store them into another array.

Comment: @JonRoy the variable i is simply used as a counter to loop through the array. It only has a local scope within the loop itself so it can't be accessed outside that for loop. You can do the equivalent by simply creating another loop.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I thought you wanted, to be honest I'm a bit confused as to what you want.

Comment: @JonRoy you can compare 2 arrays of different sizes by using 2 variables to keep track of the indices and making the statement that checks if the loop should continue the size of the smaller array . If you need to compare them off by some number you simply make them one that number before you start looping.

Comment: @James In the code, I have an array of numbers array[i]. I have a second array newArray[j] (whch has 4 less entries that array[i]), I need to compare the 3rd entry in array[i] with the 4th entry in newArray[j] if you look at the picture, Its just like that, the first row is the array[i] and the second column is the newArray[j]

Comment: @yitzih So how could i access the array outside of that loop?

Comment: @JonRoy i is just a variable index. You can access a specific index anywhere by using an exact number or by using another variable.

Comment: @JonRoy What you are trying to do should be solved by the following code `for (int i = 0; i < array2.lenght; i++) { if (array1[i] > array2[i + 2]) //do whatever }`

Comment: @yitzih Thanks! But why would the +2 be on the array2?  The array 2 has 4 less values and it doesnt start until two after the begging of array1, should the 2 be on the array 1 ?

Comment: @JonRoy I just put it on a random one. switch it around as necessary

Comment: @yitzih so the +2 means it moves two over in the indices?

Comment: i is the index of the array. If you need to access one array starting indicies after it you would use plus and if you need to acess an index 2 less you use -. After rethinking it, in your case you want to set i = 2 to begin with and then have the smaller array use `array[i-2]`

Comment: @yitzih   This is what i have, it doesn't work, it leaves out a value on the end of the first Array. any suggestions?                                                             `for (int i = 2; i < newArray.length; i++)
  { 
   if(array[i] > newArray[i-2] + 0.999) 
   {
    tempVal = array[i];
    System.out.println(tempVal);

   }
   

  }` EDIT: Nevermind. got it now. Thanks for the help dude

Comment: @yitzih Actually, it wont calculate correctly. Its printing out the whole of array[i] not just the values which are bigger, any tips?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to answer that without seeing your entire code now. The best thing to do would be to ask another question with the new code